# Getting unkown key in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

when I try to do an ng-repeat over an array of hashes, it appears the key becomes the index. So how can I get the key to an object like this?

```
[
    {
    "3000:501:001": {
        "End Date": "05/05/2013",
        "Term": "Spring Semester 2013",
        "Title": "Cooperative Education",
        "Career": "Graduate",
        "Section": "001",
        "Days": "T.B.A.",
    },
    {
    "6200:660:801": {
        "End Date": "05/05/2013",
        "Term": "Spring Semester 2013",
        "Career": "Graduate",
        "Section": "801",
        "Days": "M",
    }
    }
]
```

When I do ng-repeat="(key, course) in courses"

key is just the index 0 and 1.

I need to get "3000:501:001" and the object that key refers to. I don't know the key name.

Comment: You could loop through the properties of the object and check that the property is part of the object itself using hasOwnProperty and then also that it matches a regular expression to get the key.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have another ng-repeat which will iterate over the object.

But I would highly recommend having a different structure for your data if possible. You could  put the colon-separated numbers as a property of the inner object.

Comment: I thought I would use this key as a way to pass to the detail to do a quick pull of that course from the json and have it be bookmarkable. Seems odd I can't get at that key in a ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

To acheive what you are expecting you wouldn't wrap your objects in array and turn them into a single object. The reason you are getting `0,1` etc is `key` in an array is it's index value

JS

```js
$scope.items={
        "3000:501:001": {
            "End Date": "05/05/2013",
            "Term": "Spring Semester 2013",
            "Title": "Cooperative Education",
            "Career": "Graduate",
            "Section": "001",
            "Days": "T.B.A."
        }
    };
```

HTML

```html
<li ng-repeat="(id,item) in items">{{id}}        
     <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{key}}: {{value}}</div>
</li>
```

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyNN7HCx1t6lHD73gTLC?p=preview

In general is more convenient to use arrays for `ng-repeat` and restructure your data as such. It will also not require an extra `ng-repeat` to access the nested object